# How can I replicate the KEYS yourKey* command using Laravel's Redis facade

Tags: php, laravel, debugging, redis

On the Redis CLI if you run `KEYS yourKey*`, it'll return all the key value pairs in your Redis cluster.

I'm trying to retrieve all keys and values in my Redis cluster via the below methods but none of it seems to work.  I've looked around the web and tried some of the suggestions below but they don't work.  I've also checked the Laravel docs but it doesn't say how to do this (or if it's even possible)

If this is possible, how can I achieve this in Laravel using the Redis Facade?

```
// This is returning null even though the redis cluster does indeed have all these keys and there are values present.
Redis::get('KEYS shopping_cart*');

// Tried this but it still returns null
Redis::get('shopping_cart*');

// Tried this but it returns Cannot use 'KEYS' with redis-cluster. 
Redis::keys('shopping_cart*');

// Tried this but it returns Cannot use 'SCAN' with redis-cluster. 
Redis::scan('shopping_cart*');
```

Comment: Didn't you ask this exact (but now deleted) question like an hour or so ago? Why did you delete that question just to repost it?

Comment: `$redis->keys('*');` ?? Put `php redis KEYS` into the Search bar and wander through the results

Comment: @RiggsFolly tried something similar using the Facade: `Redis::keys('*');` but it doesn't work.